# Retrieving something comparable to ResultSetMetaData (JDBC) with TDBC

Tags: tcl, resultset, sqldatatypes, tdbc

Using JDBC (Java) always provides a lot of information about the result of a query. This is sometimes crucial, i. e. to know whether to display the result of a column left flush (strings) or right flush (numbers).

TDBC (Tcl database connectivity) seems to lack this capability. While it is true that within Tcl "everything is a string", it is sometimes necessary to know whether something is numeric, date, string or whatever kind of data type a result column has.

It's easy to ask the database for the column types of existing tables or views, but an individual query with computed columns can deliver values of types unknown beforehand. An easy example for this is `SELECT current_timestamp;` - there is no table you could ask for the data type.

I would have liked to add the tag 'TDBC', but that was not possible:

> Creating the new tag 'tdbc' requires at least 1500 reputation. Try something from the existing tags list instead.

Comment: So, you are asking, sugesting that [`$resultset columns`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TdbcCmd/tdbc_resultset.htm) should return a richer collection of metadata about the computed columns, like `$dbconn columns MyTable MyColumn` does?

Comment: Exactly. $resultset columns only contains column names, no data types. Even if Tcl itself doesn't care, it may be valuable information for further processing. JDBC's metadata are a good example for what I', thinking of.

Comment: Made the tag `tdbc` for you (and populated its wiki with basic info). May you do great things with it!

Comment: @HolgerJakobs I think this is a fair request, but SO is not the place for it. You may open up a ticket at https://core.tcl-lang.org/tdbc/ticket. While for most tdbc implementations this should be straighforward (e.g., tdbc::postgres), it will be more difficult for tdbc::sqlite3. The reason is that the latter is purely scripted, does not use the C client lib. And there is no way to get this info. Also, it needs some thoughts so that existing programs using `$resultset columns` will not break (backward compat, an important mantra in the Tcl verse).